# WSL in Windows PowerShell (x86)

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

What is difference between `Windows PowerShell (x86)` and `Windows PowerShell`? Why I can't run `wsl.exe` in `Windows PowerShell (x86)` while it runs fine in `Windows PowerShell`?

Comment: One is a 32-bit PowerShell prompt the other is 64-bit. Without specifics the rest of the question cannot be answered

Comment: See [File System Redirector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `wsl.exe` is in `C:\Windows\System32`, this means that it is a 64-bit program.
If it was 32-bit, it would have been found in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

On the other hand, the indication
`(x86)` is by convention used for 32-bit programs,
while omitting any such often means 64-bit programs.

While a 64-bit program can launch a 32-bit child program, the opposite is impossible.

This is why the 32-bit `Windows PowerShell (x86)` cannot launch the 64-bit `wsl`.